# How to iterate checked checkedbox data in kendo gird?

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, checkbox, kendo-grid

I am a new programmer and I have some problems:

- 1. I have a grid with checkbox column. 
     Let say there are 10 rows of data and I checked 5 of them. **How to loop 5 of them to get those datas?**
- 2. On the header of checkbox column, there is a single checkbox (check All).

  If I checked it, all the checkbox bellow is automatically checked. I already handle that, the question is **how to enable/disable it?**.
  The condition is: if the name column contain the same name, "`check all`" is enable.
   If the name column is contain different name, it will be disable.

Comment: Where is the code you've tried? Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I have checkboxes in my grid to delete rows which may give you some ideas. Below is the function call when the "Delete Row" button is clicked:

```
var removeLine = function(){
    var cnt = $('#tableMakanan input:checked').length;
    if( cnt == 0 ){
        alert('Nothing is selected.');
        return;
    }

    if( confirm("Are you sure you want to delete selected row(s)?") ){

        $.each( $('#tableMakanan :checkbox:checked').closest('tr'), function() {
            $('#tableMakanan').data().kendoGrid.removeRow( $(this) );
        })

    }
}
```

Or if you wish to get the data out from each row, in the $.each loop you can do:

```
var row = $('#tableMakanan').data().kendoGrid.dataItem( $(this) );
console.log( row.fieldName );
```

Comment: If your question has been answered, please make sure to accept an answer for further references @RyandhikaRukmana :)

Comment: Nah, how I do that? @Cowbell

Comment: Click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. @RyandhikaRukmana